# Fail to run propel command

Tags: php-7, propel2

I have some old systems that run Propel 2 on PHP 5.
Now I try to upgrade the OS and PHP.
The PHP version I use is 7.3.7

I can install propel successfully via composer
but when I run propel command I got an error.

```
PS D:\code\testPropel> .\vendor\bin\propel reverse "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=att;user=root;password="
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\code\testPropel\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Common\Config\PropelConfiguration.php on line 32 and at least 1 expected in D:\code\testPropel\vendor\symfony\config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 D:\code\testPropel\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Common\Config\PropelConfiguration.php(32): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder->__construct()
#1 D:\code\testPropel\vendor\symfony\config\Definition\Processor.php(50): Propel\Common\Config\PropelConfiguration->getConfigTreeBuilder()
#2 D:\code\testPropel\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Common\Config\ConfigurationManager.php(197): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->processConfiguration(Object(Propel\Common\Config\PropelConfiguration), Array)
#3 D:\code\testPropel\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Common\Config\ConfigurationManager.php(47): Propel\Common\Config\Configuratio in D:\code\testPropel\vendor\symfony\config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder.php on line 26
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is due to some sort of backwards compatibility with a symfony package.  I've isolated it to 3 of the needed symfony components that updated for me this last composer update.

symfony/filesystem (v5.1.0 => v3.4.22), symfony/finder (v5.1.0 => v3.4.22), symfony/config (v5.0.8 => v3.4.22)  

Check your project for these leaps. (Perhaps by loading a previous composer.lock that was working)

Comment: Yes, if possible you need to downgrade to symfony 4 for now. I did that and the propel reverse command worked successfully. See https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/1562#issuecomment-643115205

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved now after propel update.